# How can I block iframes with uBlock-origin?

Tags: adblock, syntax, ublock-origin

I want to define a uBlock-origin filter for iframes on a certain website, whose sources is some other website. Is this possible? If so, what's the appropriate syntax?

Comment: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Advanced-user-features, then use dynamic filtering: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Dynamic-filtering:-quick-guide